# Huge difference in execution duration with suspending function

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I'm still trying to wrap my head around suspending functions and the difference (if there's any) between an IO-bound and a CPU-bound suspending function, and other things.

I'm launching a coroutine in the main thread and running a cpu-intensive function in differente ways to see what happens.

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        launch {
            val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
            Log.d("test", "start: $start")

            fib(24)

            val finish = System.currentTimeMillis()
            Log.d("test", "finish: $finish")
            Log.d("test", "duration: ${finish - start}")
        }
    }
```

I've tried these three variations of the `fib` function:

```
private fun fib(x: Int): Int =
    if (x <= 1) x else fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
```

The regular way: the xml is NOT inflated immediately, and the function takes 0.1 SECONDS to run.

```
private suspend fun fib(x: Int): Int =
    if (x <= 1) x else fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
```

Regular way + `suspend` keyword: the xml is NOT inflated immediately, and the function takes 1.3 SECONDS to run.

```
private suspend fun fib(x: Int): Int =
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { if (x <= 1) x else fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2) }
```

Regular way + `suspend` keyword + wraping it with `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)`: the xml IS inflated immediately, and the function takes 25 SECONDS to run.

Could anybody shed a light as to why there's such a difference in the duration between the three functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
private fun fib(x: Int): Int =
    if (x <= 1) x else fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
```

This is your base case, an extremely inefficient recursive implementation of Fibonacci. It computes `fib(x - 1)` completely independently from `fib(x - 2)`, which results in an exponential explosion of function calls. To compute `fib(24)` it makes about (golden ratio)<sup>24</sup> = 103,682 calls.

```
private suspend fun fib(x: Int): Int =
    if (x <= 1) x else fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
```

Semantically this is exactly the same as above. A function declared as suspendable, but with zero suspension points. It is slower due to the overhead of the CPS transformation inherent to suspendable functions.

```
private suspend fun fib(x: Int): Int =
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { if (x <= 1) x else fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2) }
```

Here you actually achieve some parallelism, but the parallel speedup is dwarfed by the overhead of dispatching very small pieces of work. Also, since to compute the nth member of the Fibonacci sequence you need the (n - 1)th and (n - 2)th already computed, creating a chain of data dependencies all the way to the base case, you can't really parallelize Fibonacci. In your case you do a lot of recomputation of the same members, so that could be improved by parallelism, but would still fall far short of a correctly implemented single-threaded solution.

Comment: "A function declared as suspendable, but with zero suspension points."
That's one of my most basic doubts: does simply declaring a function as suspendable change anything? I guess not, right? What would be a 'suspention point' in this case?

Comment: Yes, it does, that's why you get different timing. It dramatically changes the implementation code of the function, involving among other things a special class which is instantiated on each call. Technically, a suspension point in a function is each place where you call a `suspend fun`. Your `fib` has two of those. However a coroutine actually gets suspended only when you explicitly call `suspendCoroutine`.

Comment: I should've written "improve anything" rather than "change anything".
I'm still having a hard time creating a mental model of how coroutines do the work, suspend the execution, resume it, etc.

Comment: Simply declaring an existing function suspendable is guaranteed to only make things worse. Usually you declare a function suspendable in order to be able to call some already defined function that actually uses suspension and resumption to good effect, like non-blocking IO.